# How to Modify the A* algorithm in order to find the first k(let's say 50) shortest paths?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, a-star

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use the A star algorithm to find the first 100 shortest paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088898/how-can-i-use-the-a-star-algorithm-to-find-the-first-100-shortest-paths)

How to modify the A* algorithm in order to find the first k(let's say 50) shortest paths ? I need to develop it as a C++ application.
Please explain. Thanks a lot friends...

Comment: What do you want to do with them? An n-th shortest path is usually the shortest path with a detour somewhere and generally useless for any practical purpose.

Comment: A* algorithm find the first shortest paths automatically.what is your problem exactly ?